# Emacs how to add close button to LaTeX mode toolbar

Tags: emacs, toolbar

The standard toolbar has close button:

[image]

While LaTeX mode toolbar doesn't have it:

[image]

How to add it to LaTeX mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `TeX-bar-TeX-buttons`.